# Looking for 1d (really 0d) thermodynamic cycle analysis progam for Linux

Tags: linux

I have been using `cyclepad` running in `wine` on my Linux system for thermodynamic cycle analysis.  Would like to investigate alternatives run natively in Linux to analyze more complex systems.  Should be able to handle complex cycles involving many different fluids, thermal devices, and connections.  Would like to analyze a complete utility boiler and get reasonable results. FOSS would be ideal but will look at any recommendations.